# How to exit from PHP code block?

Tags: php, html

In PHP, is it possible to exit from a PHP code block (i.e. the PHP tags)?

```
<?php
    if (!A) phpexit();
    print("1");
?>

<?php
    print("2");
?>
```

So if `A` was true, then the result is `12`, and if `A` was false, then result is `2`.

I know you can do this with if statement or something, but I want to know if there is also some special PHP function that can do this.

Comment: No, there is no such thing. I even can't imagine where you could use it.

Comment: Whatever happened to `if`?

Comment: What you need is `goto` but `goto` = **poor design**... There's `if else` for what you need.

Comment: Brake and continue

Comment: @GuchoCa `break` and `continue` are for loop-structures only. "break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure." stands in the php documentation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is the [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) operator but I strongly advise against using this kind of tricks ("spaghetti code"). You better use structured `if` blocks, there is nothing wrong with them.

Before using `goto`, consider *alternative solutions*: for example, you may `include` different scripts depending on the `A` condition.

[image]

Comment: I don't downvote this just because of the constructive `include` part of the answer. The picture is funny, but not constructive. I know it's popular to be agains goto, but goto itself doesn't always mean spaghetti code. To break the program flow, like to jump from the middle of cycle into middle of another function is misusing and spaghetti. But if the jump is clear and doesn't break the context (like in this case), I believe it is OK to use.

Comment: @JanTuroň: Yes, I still use goto in some of my C programs, for example to reach a general error handling block from within a nested loop. The problem with goto is that, once you start using it in legitimate ways, you soon start using it to "patch" poorly designed control flows. However, your point is good... and I always try to make my answers constructive.

Comment: Why doesn't php just make a function like what I did in my first example `phpexit();` just to exit from a php tag? Isn't it the same concept as the `exit();` or `break`. Those two are basically doing a `goto`, to either exit from a for/while loop or exit from the whole page?

Comment: I think that nobody felt that need, simply... Moreover a <?php block is not a structured block, in fact an if can be interrupted by ?> and resumed with <?php. In that case, think about the mess that would come out if such a function did exist.

Comment: @omega why do we need extra jump's when we can do it already with do-while, if or goto? (and as gd1 points out: it wouldn't be consistent)

Comment: ok I will just avoid goto, and use if blocks then. Thanks everyone.

Comment: The claim *The problem with goto is that, once you start using it in legitimate ways, you soon start using it to "patch" poorly designed control flows* has the same logic like *The problem with knife is that, once you start using it in legitimate ways, you soon start using it to kill people*. If somebody tends to use hacky way of coding or killing people, he will find his way even without goto or knife. Goto and knife just require more responsibility than break and sponge.

Comment: I like to imagine that you had this reply ready in a browser tab back in 2013, which got somehow forgotten, and you hit enter just now. ;) Anyway, we've been rehearsing the trite debate over the use and misuse of potentially harmful tools, and I am guilty of starting it. I concede that someone prone to using hacky solutions is going to do it even without `goto`. However, I'd rework our analogy like so: if you see someone with a knife pointed at their own heart asking "Can I?", you are allowed to oversimplify a bit by yelling "No: knife = bad!" to save them. That's how `goto` memes were born.

Answer (score 21):

There could be two solutions:

**1) less hacky**

include the code you have in the block in separate files. You may use `return` in them to stop processing included file

```
//file1.php
if (!A) return;
print("1");

// file2.php
print("2");

<?php include "file1.php";?>
<?php include "file2.php";?>
```

**2) more hacky** (others will probably kill me)

Put the block into `do { ... } while(false);` block and break from it

```
<?php do {
    if (!A) break;
    print("1");
} while(false); ?>

<?php do {
    print("2");
} while(false); ?>
```

Comment: +1. I'd kill you for the first: wasting a whole file for only one code line :-P But the second I like :-)

Comment: I believe the question was narrowed and the block is some complex consistent code deserving separated file. Maybe. The second one is definitely more suitable for short parts, but may be scary on the first sight.

Comment: +1 for the "include" solution and it's good to remark that, if the code blocks are relatively small and simple, than there is no need for inclusion, goto, or "hacky" while loops, and a simple if will do the trick.

Comment: @bwoebi: completely OT, but today you are #6 week rank, you even beat Jon Skeet. Congratulations!

Comment: @JanTuroň I just saw, thank you… but there are still 5 others who beat me :-P

Answer (score 12):

No there isn't any. But what you could do is putting a label at the end of each block and then use `goto` (not recommended, but when you don't want a big `if`... (p.s.: see the answer of @gd1 as a hint here ;-P)).

```
<?php
    if (!A) goto exit_1;
    print("1");
exit_1: ;
?>

<?php
    print("2");
exit_2: ;
?>
```

Comment: -1 This is extremely bad coding practice as it leads to spaghetti code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: @Precastic I didn't recommend it, I said it would be the only alternative if the OP strongly feels to have to use it.

Comment: @Precastic: from your link: *complex and tangled control structure, especially one using many GOTOs* - see the word MANY? Look at Matthias Buelens code (no offense) - this is spaghetti code with tangled structure. The above example is not tangled at all. Goto doesn't always mean spaghetti.

Comment: Let me rephrase then... ANY time a GOTO is used you have start looking for where it points to. There is no solution in the world that requires a GOTO that can't be done using some other control logic which is infinitely clearer. MOST solutions are big enough to make goto a pain to trace. Up-voting an answer that doesn't explain how bad using goto is encourages bad programming from inexperienced users.

Comment: @Precastic a) is a `strg + f` so hard? And I agree that you should … mostly avoid goto, but there are use cases. Can't instantly tell one in PHP, but in C you can't break multiple nested loops at once. So you simply put there a label at the end of the loops and use goto. If you have X gotos near to each other, or worse overlapping, then you should clearly redesign your code, but nobody should complain about a goto alone where the label is near. (tl;dr: linear jumping is okay (following the programs flow), cross-jumping isn't (jumping back, forward, from one label to the next etc.).)

Comment: @bwoebi We are not talking about any other language other than PHP here. Yes there are use cases in other languages.

Comment: @Precastic You didn't get my point. I meant, when we can live with it in another language where it has the exact same syntax, why should we disallow it in PHP? It's (maybe) not best practice, but ***there's nothing wrong with it***.

Comment: This is my final comment. I got your point. My point is that if you choose to use goto in PHP you are programming badly, period. If someone jumps off a cliff will you follow just because it is there & they did?

Comment: @Precastic Also, it's hard to explain why goto is bad … I can say spaghetti code, but not everyone knows the real problems with it. You need to see what's wrong with it. You learn from experience, not because someone tries to demonstrate why it's bad. Myself, I once tried to write something with a lot of gotos … and failed because of the resulting big mess. And stop just saying `goto is bad`. A goto alone not bad (when it's not going into spaghetti code), it's just some people who cannot live with it. Why? I don't now. (It's like something religious...)

Answer (score 8):

If this is for anything but an experiment, **you are doing it wrong**. Stop doing include-oriented programing as start learning OOP.

Well ... you could always wrap the `<?php ?>` content in anonymous function;

```
<?php $f = function () use (&$a) {

    if ($a)
    { 
        echo 1;
        return;
    }
    echo 2;

};$f(); ?>

<?php $f = function () {

    echo 2;

};$f(); ?>
```

This would work in PHP 5.3+.  And if you need to share variable, you can inject them in the scope with `use()` statement in the definition.

But let me repeat:

> **If you want to do something like this in production code, you are doing it wrong.**

Comment: the `do { } while (0);` is smarter. Doing it with a Closure is correct, but a) slower and using more memory and b) not as beautiful. (but I don't downvote: it's correct)

Comment: Hmm..  Now I'm curious.  Do the immediately-called functions (like `(function() { .. })()`) work in PHP (like in Javascript), or is that a syntax error?

Comment: @Izkata, i actually tried that initially, but is did not work. Parser was bitching about unexpected parentheses.

Comment: Obviously no downvote, but I may observe that the one who writes in PHP, which is basically a chaos-oriented scripting tool with some late OOP hack, shouldn't fear `include`s, especially if the alternative is some *hackier* workaround. :) I agree with your final remark.

Comment: Well ... of course a return from `include` would be the cleanest solutions.

Comment: Do not use the closing ?> tag

Answer (score 6):

If you respect geek pop culture too much and feel you need to fit in (and get popular!), here's a solution without `goto`:

```
<?php
call_user_func(function() {
    if (!A) return;
    print("1");
});
?>

<?php
    print("2");
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, and it wouldn't make sense. Imagine you *could* do this and you had this piece of code:

```
<?php
    if (!A) phpexit();

    if (B) {
?>
        <b>Foo</b>
<?php
    }
?>
    <i>Baz</i>
```

Where would `phpexit()` jump to? The `then` block of the `if (B)` jumps out and in of a PHP block, but you don't want to jump to `<b>Foo</b>` from `if (!A)`, right? It wouldn't make sense to jump into a `then` block without checking the condition.

[As gd1 already showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135800/1321716), you could do this with `goto` but it'd make your code unstructured. You'd make it very hard on yourself (and future maintainers of your code) to understand the flow of your code when your code jumps around all over the place.

In low-level languages (i.e. assembly) you *only* have jumps to work with, but in higher languages you abstract those away with structures such as `if`, `for` and `while`. These provide structure by *intentionally* preventing you from jumping to anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into several situations where the rest of a PHP code block needs to be skipped over  due to an error condition (database connection error, invalid input, etc.).  As a student, my professor simply uses `die`, which stops parsing of the file altogether, leaving the page incomplete, without the footer or even the HTML closing tags `</body></html>`.  Even when there is an error, there is no reason to generate invalid HTML by cutting off the closing tags.

Of course, a purely structured approach would use `if` statements, and this is preferable to `goto` in the vast majority of situations.  However, I feel that if you're just trying to jump out of a PHP code block, putting large segments of code in an `if`/`else` structure is rather inelegant and can actually make the code harder to understand than simply using a `goto` statement that jumps to the very end of the PHP block, just before the `?>`, since it becomes hard to remember that a whole bunch of code is in fact part of a conditional statement 50+ lines below the `if` or `elseif` lines.

Everyone says that `goto` statements are bad, but there are valid uses for `goto` that make the code easier to understand, such as jumping out of deeply nested control structures and jumping to the end of a PHP code block (given that no built-in language construct exists for doing that).

A code construct like `goto` is not inherently evil.  It comes down to how you use it.